# Unable to check disk input output in Fedora core 2

Tags: linux, unix

I have `Fedora Core release 2 (Tettnang)` in my system and I am unable to check `disk IO`with the given command.

```
# sar -b 3 10
```

Output as given

```
11:24:10 AM       tps      rtps      wtps   bread/s   bwrtn/s

11:24:13 AM      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00

11:24:16 AM      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

Here, in the above output i am getting 0.00, what could be the reason and why it is not showing correct output. does it mean it does not command support on `Fedora core2` . Please suggest the same.

Comment: These questions are purely Unix related questions should not be asked in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using an older version of `sysstat`
You should consider to upgrade to `sysstat-5.0.5-9` which you can find [here](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/4/x86_64/os/Fedora/RPMS/sysstat-5.0.5-9.fc.x86_64.rpm)

Or better update atleast to  sysstat-6.0.1-3.2.1.x86_64.rpm  can be find [here](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/5/x86_64/os/Fedora/RPMS/sysstat-6.0.1-3.2.1.x86_64.rpm)